# Why is QFontMetrics::lineSpacing() smaller than the height of the characters' bounding boxes?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, ubuntu

This happens on Linux.

The problem shows when executing this code (I'm drawing in the paint event of a widget):

```
painter.drawText(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, QString("0"), &charBoundingBox);
qDebug() << "bounding box height" << charBoundingBox.height();
qDebug() << "lineSpacing" << painter.fontMetrics().lineSpacing();
qDebug() << "leading" << painter.fontMetrics().leading();
qDebug() << "height" << painter.fontMetrics().height();
qDebug() << painter.font();
```

It outputs:

```
bounding box height 11 
lineSpacing 7 
leading -1 
height 8 
QFont( "Digital-7,10,-1,5,50,0,0,0,0,0" )
```

Notice the height of the bounding box for the character is `11`, while the line spacing is `7`. This is partly because the leading is negative, but even without that, the font height is still smaller.

How does Qt calculate the character bounding box it returns? Its height obviously is not derived from `fontMetrics::height` and `fontMetrics::leading`.

Comment: Why not? Typography is complicated.

Comment: Because if the linespace is smaller than the characters, the characters would overlap. In fact, this is what alerted me to the problem in the first place

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that the height of the bounding box returned by the painter will be the same as the font height. Also, the line spacing is the sum of the height and leading of the font. If the leading for a font is negative, the line spacing will be smaller than the height.

Furthermore, to make sure you're using the correct metrics, you should probably use painter.fontMetrics() instead of constructing a QFontMetrics(font).

In any event, to make sure which of the above is happening in your situation, you should print out the font leading and font height separately (using painter.fontMetrics()).

Comment: This time I tested with `painter.fontMetrics()`. It seems that this is indeed the case for most of the fonts on Linux, the leading is `-1`, while the height was equal to the bounding box. But for some fonts, including `digital-7`, the leading was `0`, while the font height was smaller than the bounding box.